# I am using Testcafe : Settings.json file. error shown in the node module

Tags: testing, automated-tests, node-modules, e2e-testing, testcafe

[image: Node Module path error]
 The path shown is "node_modules/qa-lib/src/step_definitions/*.js"

but under node modules folder there is no qa-lib

Answer (score 1):

Either install this module if it exists, or get rid of this line.

This file (Settings.json) is not a part of TestCafe. It is a part of the third-party extension you are using. Refer to the extension documentation:
https://github.com/alexkrechik/VSCucumberAutoComplete#settings-example

Comment: Thanks Alex, i got rid of the line . :-)